# Add Path / Auto Load Path For Grape API Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am using Grape to build my API, and according to the documentation, I added the following lines to `application.rb so that all`app/api` ruby scripts are added to the path, as well as allowing auto-reload for development mode:

```
config.paths.add "app/api", :glob => "**/*.rb"
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]
```

I also added a piece of code in config/initializers as asked to. However, neither auto-reload nor the paths are working properly.

For the path, I need to explicitly add everything using `require` at the main API file that I am using (I separated my Grape files into files + directories under `app/api`. If I remove the require, I get:

```
NoMethodError    
undefined method `call' for V1:Module
```

The auto-reload is also not working at all. It does not auto-reload when I change something.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Post your app somewhere and email the Grape mailing list. There's an app in https://github.com/dblock/grape-on-rails that does all of this and has been tested to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you split api into many files you need mount that parts. See [documentation for modules](https://github.com/intridea/grape#modules)

> These don't have to be different versions, but may be components of
>   the same API.

```
class APP::API < Grape::API
  mount APP::Groups
  mount APP::Users
end
```